# Remote IP from request on http server

Tags: node.js

is there any way to know the remote IP adress form a request on on the http server?
Using "net" for a socket connection is socket.remoteAddress but for the http server I get undifined for the same .remoteAddress

Regards

Answer (score 22):

I'm just adding this because I came across this article and it still took me a little bit of time to figure out it was as you see in the following:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello ' + req.connection.remoteAddress + '!');
    console.log("request received from: " + req.connection.remoteAddress);
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: Note the following: 'req.connection.remoteAddress' only gets populated *AFTER* you send the response with 'res.end()'. Before that the behaviour is not very consistent :S

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [`request.connection`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#request.connection) method to retrieve the [`net.Socket`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net.Socket) object, where you can then use your `socket.remoteAddress` property.

Comment: Can you provide a code example for this? I don't seem to have a `remoteAddress` variable in `net.Socket` AKA `request.connection.server`.

Comment: Basically, console.log("request received from: " + req.connection.remoteAddress);

Answer (score 0):

here is sample of getting IP address on node server:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(5432, () => { });
server.on('connection', (stream) => {
  console.log("someone connected: " + stream.remoteAddress);
});
```